# Checking component Instance in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am checking the component instance if component added to DOM or not based on the static field.I am assigning this to the static field.

childComponent.ts

```
static childInstance : ChildComponent;
constructor() {
  ChildComponent.childInstance = this; 
}
```

parentComponent.ts

```
static Arr = Array<{ id: string, msg: string}>();
if(ChildComponent.childInstance){
   parentComponent.Arr.push('1','new msg');
}
```

The above code is working fine and displaying the array message in chrome and i am having issue in IE11. while loading the message got displaying in IE11 and after that it is disappearing.

Why it is behaving in IE11 ?

Comment: can you share the error which you are getting

Comment: I am not getting any error. the message what i am pushing into array is not coming even the child component is loaded and able to see it in debugger.

Comment: you need to push object

Comment: parentComponent.Arr.push({
id: '1', msg: 'new msg'
});

Try like this.

Comment: yes it will push into array but if the component instance present then only i need to push the object otherwise no.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for the same

Comment: I am new to stackBlitz but i created sample one and getting errors while importing.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqkusi